# Java recursion print directory subdirectory files

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to loop through a folder and list all files with a specific file ending. I'm trying to solve this problem with a recursive method but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
private int counter = 0;
public void printAllJavaFiles(File directory) {
        printFile(directory);
        File[] subDirectories = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : subDirectories) {
            printAllJavaFiles(file);
        }
}

private void printFile(File file) {
    // Get file extension
    String fileExtension = "";
    int i = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
    if (i >= 0) {
        fileExtension = file.getName().substring(i + 1);
    }

    if (fileExtension.equals("java")) {
        System.out.println("File: " + file.getName() + " Size: " + file.length());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? I really have no idea how to go up and down in the directory structure. It just enters the first folder and once it's done listing it's files it throws a nullpointerexception.

Comment: You should take a look at `java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree`

Comment: I have to solve this issue specifically using a recursive method.

Comment: Where do you get the NPE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `File.isDirectory()` method. Like this:

```
public void printAllJavaFiles(File directory) {
    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        File[] subDirectories = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : subDirectories) {
            printAllJavaFiles(file);
        }
    }else {
        printFile(directory);
    }
}
```

Documentation on that method here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()

The idea is that for every file you check if it is a folder, if so, make the recursive call. If not, simply print the file.

Comment: Thank you for saving me from this headache.

Comment: Will do as soon as it allows me to :) 5-6 minutes remaining.

Comment: hi thanks it lists everything on sd card but how to make it list only folders without files??